# Using openapi-typescript-codegen, why does this Swagger schema produce a model of Record<string, any>?

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi

My swagger.json includes this schema:

```
"schemas": {
            "BuildFruitBody": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "format": "double"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": true
            }
        },
```

However, when I generate the axios client via `npx openapi-typescript-codegen -i ./swagger.json -o src/services/api -c axios`, the resulting model is as below:

```
/* generated using openapi-typescript-codegen -- do no edit */
/* istanbul ignore file */
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */

export type BuildFruitBody = Record<string, any>;
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Why doesn't the model reflect the schema?

Full swagger.json below:

```
{
    "components": {
        "examples": {},
        "headers": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "requestBodies": {},
        "responses": {},
        "schemas": {
            "BuildFruitBody": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "format": "double"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": true
            }
        },
        "securitySchemes": {}
    },
    "info": {
        "title": "backend",
        "contact": {}
    },
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "paths": {
        "/swagger.json": {
            "get": {
                "operationId": "Get",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Ok",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "tags": [
                    "swagger"
                ],
                "security": [],
                "parameters": []
            }
        },
        "/fruit": {
            "post": {
                "operationId": "Get",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Ok",
                        "content": {
                            "application/json": {
                                "schema": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "tags": [
                    "fruit"
                ],
                "security": [],
                "parameters": [],
                "requestBody": {
                    "required": true,
                    "content": {
                        "application/json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/BuildFruitBody"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "servers": [
        {
            "url": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong here?

Not within the code as far as I can see.

> Why doesn't the model reflect the schema?

Actually, it does reflect the schema. But perhaps it's the mental model that is differently reflecting the schema model or not yet well understood?

---

When given the following in a JSON Schema (cf. [`additionalProperties` JSON Schema Core DRAFT-2020-12](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core#section-10.3.2.3))

```
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": true
```

then the [`Record<Keys, Type>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

```
 Record<string, any>
```

seems legit as in JSON Text an attribute/property name is a JSON String and can be *any* of the seven: JSON Object, JSON Array, JSON String, JSON Number, `"true"`, `"false"` and `"null"` (cf. json.org).

These attribute/property values can be expressed as [`any` in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).

---

The best suggestion I can give is to put it under automated test and then confront yourself with the problem that the first test did fail unexpectedly (or didn't fail for the expected reason), then fix it.

Either the schema or the expectation, depends on your requirements.

---

And as *[defraggled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9466397/defraggled)*
 confirms per comment below:

> Ah yes, setting `additionalProperties: false` resolves it. Thanks

The requirement was indeed to not have additional properties (which could have been left out for validation).

Which is a strong sign that it could have been left out of the schema alltogether, `additionalProperties` has been moved from JSON Schema Validation to JSON Schema Core recently (DRAFT-2020-12).

Comment: The schema is equivalent to `{id?: number;  name?: string}`. How is that reflected by `Record<any, any>` ?

Comment: @defraggled: Sorry, late edit: You have type object with additional properties true. And I've seen `Record<string, any>` not `Record<any, any>` (just wondering where you picked it up, couldn't find it apart your comment).

Comment: Ah yes, setting `additionalProperties: false` resolves it. Thanks

Comment: @defraggled: If that is your requirement, try as well to leave it out, then you've learned which defaults are applied. Also take some note what your understanding is which draft version of JSON Schema is at play here, as JSON  Schema still is a moving target and you may want to have some guardrails as it progresses.

Answer (score 0):

you likely stumbled across an expected behavior of JSON Schema but not your own expectation in that `additionalProperties:true` *does not* constrain other properties from being sent in your data instance.

`additionalProperties: true` OR the lack of an `additionalProperties` definition as a constraint are equivalent to each other.

These two schemas are equivalent and would match `Record<string, any>`

```json
{
    "BuildFruitBody": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "number",
                "format": "double"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": true
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "BuildFruitBody": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "number",
                "format": "double"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "object"
    }
}
```

JSON Schema is a constraints based data validation language. It only validates the constraints provided.  Since you defined `additionalProperties: true`, the TypeScript model of `Record<string,any>` is the proper annotation because properties are unconstrained by your use of `additionalProperties:true`

---

Only when you constrain the schema to the properties defined would you find the expected TypeScript definition

```json
{
    "BuildFruitBody": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "number",
                "format": "double"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

```js
/* generated using openapi-typescript-codegen -- do no edit */
/* istanbul ignore file */
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */

export type BuildFruitBody = {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
};
```